# How to assign letters of alphabet to numbers for Caesar cipher in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, encryption

I wrote a program that encrypts the numbers corresponding to letters of an alphabet and decrypts it but how do I make it so that when I ask for input I assign each letter to it's number then do the operations and print the encryption and decryption of the message without several lines of code? This is my program:

```
print "Caesar's Cipher\n\n";
print "Reference:\n\n";
print "A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L    M\n";
print "0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11   12\n\n";
print "N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y    Z\n";
print "13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24   25\n";
print "\nEnter a Message (User numbers separated by space):\n";
$string = <>; 

@sarray = split(" ",$string);

foreach $x (@sarray){
    if ($x >=0 && $x <= 25){
        $x = ($x+3)%26;
    } else {
        print "Entered incorrect message.\n"; 
        die;
    }
}
print "\nEncryption: \n";
print "@sarray\n";

foreach $x (@sarray){
    if ($x >=0 && $x <= 25){
        $x = ($x-3)%26;
    } else {
        print "Entered incorrect message.\n"; 
        die;
    }
}

print "Decryption: \n";
print "@sarray\n";
```

I want to be able to just input something like "HELLO" and then it will encrypt the message and decrypt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to consider upper and lower case, numeric digits, plus the space character and punctuation.  Presently you handle only uppercase alpha.  You need a hash that maps characters to numbers, and one that maps the other way.

```
$inputChar = character to be encoded
$charset = " ABCDEFGHI...Zabcdef...z0123456789!@#$%^&*...";
$code = index($charset,$char);
# encode here as in your example using length($charset) instead of 26
$outputChar = substr($charset,$code,1);
```

Apply this logic to all the characters in your message to build the encrypted message.

Answer (score 2):

The solution offered by Jim above exceeds what is being asked, since the OP only wants alphabet characters from A to Z. An easier way to implement this would be, taking J as an example search:

```
my @alpha = ('A'..'Z');
my $s = 'J';
my( $index ) = grep{ $alpha[ $_ ] eq $s } 0..$#alpha;
```